# trim video files via audio track information

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-editing

Is there a way to pass a folder of .mp4 files and trim them by audio track? Say the first 20 seconds has no loud audio and the last 20 seconds has no loud audio, is there a way to remove the first and last 20 seconds of the video file, trimming it somehow? Using Kdenlive or another program? Could it be tuned by decibel level? *I want to trim the beginning and end of the clips, where/when I am not talking.*

I might need to create a command line program that can do this. Does anyone know how to read a video file and determine the points at which the audio is first and last loud and then trim the file by the audio points?

*ffmpeg* seems like the program to this, but I am not entirely sure. I could do this manually with Kdenlive, but looking to do this automatically.

```
Input: folder of .mp4 files
Output: new folder of .mp4 files, first and last quiet parts are trimmed
```

*****An advanced program could also just delete chunks of video where I am not talking for more than 3 seconds, just delete those sections, and those sections could be anywhere in the video, not just the beginning/end.

[image]

Using the above image as an example, we would trim the first 15 seconds and the last 7 seconds and there might be 2 or 3 seconds to remove from the time around 1:06-1:08, which was a section where I had to take a look at some notes before returning to speaking.

Comment: Here is a post how to trim videos with ffmpeg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444194/cutting-the-videos-based-on-start-and-end-time-using-ffmpeg How to determine the start and end times programatically is another story - silencedetection could be it https://superuser.com/questions/931533/ffmpeg-split-a-video-using-silencedetect